# Как скомпилировать .py в .exe?

Tags: python, windows

Напишите, пожалуйста, подробно, как преобразовать файл с расширением .py в .exe файл?

Comment: Куда уж еще подробнее: [Компиляция python3 в exe](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте cx_freze или pyinstaller.

Конечно, не у всех получается с pyinstall, но советую почитать про способ компиляции с pyinstaller и cx_freeze.

Но учтите, что это НЕ ПОЛНОЦЕННАЯ КОМПИЛЯЦИЯ! Потому что Python интерпритируемый язык, значит - все компиляторы для него считаются НЕДОКОМПИЛЯТОРАМИ!

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Но если очень хочется то можно в pyd + стартер из питона