# Как скомпилировать python скрипт на exe для Windows 7, 8, 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я использую pyinstaller для компиляции, но при запуске приложения выдаётся ошибка на VirtualBox Windows 7. `Запуск программы не возможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-core-path-|1-1-0.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать .py в .exe?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399268/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я узнал что Python3.9 не поддерживает Windows 7, поэтому установил Python3.8. Теперь всё работает :)

Answer (score 1):

**Запустите средство проверки системных файлов (System File Checker), чтобы восстановить поврежденный или отсутствующий файл `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`:**

Для этого запустите командную строку от имени администратора и введите команду

```
sfc /scannow
```

Средство проверки системных файлов начнет поиск неполадок, связанных с `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`, а также других неполадок с системными файлами.
Для завершения процесса следуйте инструкциям на экране.

---

**Если не помогло, то попробуйте обновить Windows:**

1. Нажмите кнопку «Пуск» в Windows
2. В поле поиска введите «Обновить» и нажмите ENTER.
3. В диалоговом окне Центра обновления Windows нажмите «Проверить наличие обновлений» (или аналогичную кнопку в зависимости от версии Windows)
4. Если обновления доступны для загрузки, нажмите «Установить обновления».

После завершения обновления следует перезагрузить ПК.

---

**Также можно вручную загрузить обновление:** https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=53840

---

*Инструкции брал [здесь](https://www.exefiles.com/ru/dll/api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0-dll/). В свое время так и решил эту проблему*

Comment: Ничего не помогло :(

Comment: Тогда попробуйте просто гуглить ошибку "*Запуск программы не возможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-core-path-|1-1-0.dll*" и смотреть способы решения на YouTube